# Need to convert MVC Razor model to aspx directive

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Having trouble to convert the following MVC Razor `@Model` to ASPX directive.
What is the `aspx` mapping for Razor `@model PagedList.IPagedList<CapitalProjects.tblSite>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="ViewPage<PagedList.IPagedList<CapitalProjects.tblSite>>" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**With Mike suggestion, I got the answers for Razor and ASPX vbhtml**

Razor: `@ModelType PagedList.IPagedList(Of CapitalProjects.tblSite)`

ASPX: `<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(Of PagedList.IPagedList (Of CapitalProjects.tblSite))" %>`